# Input tag is not working in IE10

Tags: php, internet-explorer, dom

```
<input type="button" value= "View Details" name = "${grApplist.sys_id}" class="viewApp" />
```

this like is working perfectly in other browser and IE below 9... But not in IE-10 Why this is happening and how to solve this

Comment: you tried by using </input > instead of plain <input /> ??

Comment: Try button tag directly... <button value="View Details">

Comment: @PreetiMaurya not working

Comment: @prembaranwal in this case name attribute is not working in button.. which mean click event is not working

Comment: @RajagopalPG might be a problem in the `name` attribute? do you see what exactly is coming when you do a view source code for that line?